# How to embed a public Mapbox style by using user's own access token

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

FCC provides a style id [from their website](https://broadbandmap.fcc.gov/#/about) which is

> https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/fcc/ck07351k218h31cp7om3z4bka.html?fresh=true&title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZmNjIiwiYSI6ImNqY2h2MnAxbDJhZjIycXBnN3cxb3FnYzAifQ.-JIKXvGZ-ZI2m7L8f92Lew#3.0/37.000000/-95.000000/0

However, when I tried to embed the style into my website, it is not working.

My code is

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'myowntoken';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: "map",
        style: "mapbox://styles/fcc/ck07351k218h31cp7om3z4bka",
        center: [-121.064242, 36.922103], // starting position
        zoom: 5
      });
```

I wonder why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that FCC only allows using this style with their token. The note on their documentation website says:

> **Note:** In order to access these layers, in the various formats below, you need a Mapbox access token. We are including a public access token in the links below since we want to make it easy for people to access broadband data in whatever format is most useful. However, if we find that the access token is being abused, and in particular being used to access maps unrelated to the broadband map, we will have no choice but to deactivate the token, and require end users to get their own token.

While it implies that you could use your own token, it seems like they didn't actually enable this functionality.

You can use the token they provided for the time being.